# JQuery OnClick not working when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a naqvigation button that when clicked should load another html page into a div with the class "main" and to do this I added an onclicklistener with JQuery. Here is the JQuery Code:

```
$('WOFButton').on('click', function(event) {
    alert("clicked");
    $('.Main').load('wof.html');
});
```

However, when I click the button nothing happens. No error messages, nothing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('#WOFButton').on('click', function(event) {`, function(event) {` try [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/), if this `WOFButton` an id

Comment: `WOFButton` is not an html tag. Hence it must be a class `.WOFButton` or id `#WOFButton`.

Comment: @Durga I spent quite a while looking and didn't notice that tiny mistake. Thanks! Next time I'll try and be more observant.

Comment: @Rithwik Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help @TimRumit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query selector is $('WOFButton').

So jQuery is looking for an element with a tag `WOFButton`

It is highly unlikely your HTML contains a tag that looks like this:

```
<WOFButton></WOFButton>
```

If you meant to get the element with Id of `WOFButton`

```
// bind <input id="WOFButton" type="button" />
$('#WOFButton').on('click', function(event) {
    alert("clicked");
    $('.Main').load('wof.html');
});
```

If you meant to get it with the class attribute `WOFButton` then:

```
// bind <input class="WOFButton" type="button" />
$('.WOFButton').on('click', function(event) {
    alert("clicked");
    $('.Main').load('wof.html');
});
```

If you meant to get it by the name attribute `WOFButton` then:

```
// bind <input name="WOFButton" type="button" />
$('[name="WOFButton"]').on('click', function(event) {
    alert("clicked");
    $('.Main').load('wof.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your selector is wrong. When you use it to select by ID it should start with # like `$('#WOFButton')`. 
Also your function needs `event.preventDefault()` function to be called to prevent default action of button to be triggered.

Comment: I didn't know about the event.preventDefault(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.WOFButton').click(function(){
  alert("clicked");
    $('.Main').load('wof.html');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="WOFButton">WOFButton</button>
```

You are selecting in wrong way because `WOFButton` this is not tag you can select this by id like `#WOFButton` or class `.WOFButton` now its working.